# Setting up PGP FTP

Tags: security, ftp, encryption, pgp

I have a situation where I need to setup a FTP server with PGP encryption. Currently I use FileZilla w/ SSL, but in this case we are required to use PGP.

Any recommended products/procedures from those who have done this? Doesn't look like FileZilla natively supports PGP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PGP is not an in-transit encryption technology as SSL/TLS is. You'll most likely need to use PGP to encrypt the files, transfer them, and then decrypt on the other side. This process could be easily automated if that is desirable.

Comment: thanks, what are the tools used to encrypt using PGP? this would be windows

Comment: Well, if you need to use the commercial PGP product, there's a windows command-line version: http://www.symantec.com/business/command-line Otherwise I'd recommend using the PGP-compatible GPL-licensed GNU Privacy Guard, which is available for Windows: http://www.gnupg.org/download/index.en.html

Comment: I've used Gnu-PGP on Windows, it works!

Answer (score 0):

**gpg** is an ideal drop in for this purpose. You can script it in windows, unix or other OS's. I implemented a scheduled file transfer for a global bank from one region to another which included **PGP** encryption at one end, automated pull from an FTP site, scripting on a Unix LPAR on an AS400 to decrypt and eventually drop into a windows fileshare. I would definitely advise gpg if you need something compatible with PGP but scriptable.

Comment: The commercial PGP *is* scriptable.

Comment: True - at the time I wasn't in a position to implement it, so I looked at gpg and it was simple and convenient.